# disposing of old gasoline

Tags: gasoline, disposal

I have an old car (1965 Mustang) that has a mostly full tank of old gasoline.  I'd like to drain the fuel tank and refill with new gas prior to trying to start it.

About the cheapest container I've seen is $20 per 5 gallons.  I can then take the old gas to the dump or burn it a gallon to a full tank of gas in one of our other vehicles. I really don't need any more gas cans and I'd need to buy two or three new gas cans to store all this gas.

I suppose if I had thought about it six months ago I could have siphoned it out a gallon or two at a time and used it to top off nearly full tanks on my other cars.

Does anyone have better options?

Thanks